# How to get all 'Post' objects where 'User' has replied?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I have a database table `Post` which stores posts created by users. Other users can create replies to these posts, stored in `PostReply` table. Now, the owner of the `Post` can accept a single `PostReply`, and the owner of `PostReply` has to know all the `Post`s they have created an accepted reply to.

Basically, the models look like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'posts')
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, default = '')

class PostReply(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'replies')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'replies')
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

The thing I'm having trouble is this: how do I retrieve all the posts where the accepted reply is the user? I know I can get all the `PostReply` objects of the user like this:

```
queryset = PostReply.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user)
```

... and I can define this queryset by filtering just the accepted ones:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(accepted = True)
```

... but I don't know how to get the related `Post` items.

To elaborate, here's a scenario:

```
User 'Foo' creates a post 1
User 'Bar' creates a reply to post 1
User 'Foo' accepted 'Bar's reply to post 1
```

Now, user 'Bar' should be able to query the server for a list of posts where his reply is the accepted one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you can try:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(postreply__owner=self.request.user, postreply__accepted=True)
```

More on [Django documentation: Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Side note: take care of the uniqueness of accepted post replies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm! The uniqueness is taken care of, I simplified the example models to contain just the bare minimum. :)